# Formatting sortcode field in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, format

In a previous post the answer to how to format data nnnnnn as nn-nn-nn was provided as :

```
SELECT 
FORMAT(CODE,'##-##-##') 
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

However the problem I have is that a leading 0 is being omitted, so 012345 is formatted to 1-23-45 instead of 01-23-45

Is there anyway I can modify the FORMAT command or is there another command I can use to support this?

Comment: ms-access does not work with T-SQL. if it's T-SQL it's either SQL Server or Sybase.

Comment: The SQL is for a payroll system that has either an Access or a SQL Server backend, so I put access and T-SQL. Apologies

Comment: nothing to be sorry about, it was just unclear. I've been here for a while and I see a lot of mismatching tags (usually people tag both MySql and Sql Server), so I thought that's the problem here as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this format.

```
SELECT FORMAT(CODE,'0#-##-##')
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f3b0f/2*

Comment: @JamesKnight It's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

Append 0 based on length of sortcode after formatting

```
SELECT 
case when len(FORMAT(012345,'##-##-##') )<8 
then '0' +cast(FORMAT(012345,'##-##-##') as varchar(8)) end
```